# importing in prop array values in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on creating a small music player program in React. I was wondering if there is a way to import all these values at once as a single import statement?

I noticed when I tried hardcoding in the values into the props array it will not work because the files are actually fetched from a /static/media directory.

Sample Code:

```
// Lightweight library for audio playing
import ReactAudioPlayer from 'react-audio-player';
import LikeBtn from './LikeBtn';
import Shuffle from '../img/shuffle_bg.jpg';
// Imports from music audio files
import track1 from '../music/Arc North - Catch Me When I Fall (ft. Sarah de Warren) [Magic Release].mp3';
import track2 from '../music/Ellis - Clear My Head.mp3';
import track3 from '../music/Jim Yosef & Alex Skrindo - Ruby [NCS Release].mp3';

// Import music covers
import bg1 from '../img/song_covers/42388294_800_800.jpg';
import bg2 from '../img/song_covers/clearhead.jpg';
import bg3 from '../img/song_covers/000377402250.jpg';

class Player2 extends React.Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      playlist: [
      // This would work because it fetches the imported value.
      {id: 1, name:'Catch Me When I Fall', author: 'Arc North ft. Sarah de Warren', img: bg1, audio: track1}, 
      // Does not work because it doesn't actually fetch the data from relative path.
      {id: 2, name:'Clear My Head', author: 'Ellis', img: '../img/song_covers/clearhead.jpg', audio:'../music/Ellis - Clear My Head.mp3},
```

Comment: If you use the public folder, you should be able to do this dynamically using URLs. https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/

Answer (score 0):

You could create a file "mediaFiles.js" like below and import only that file

```
 export default {
  img1: require('../Assets/img/shuffle_bg.jpg'),
  track1: require('../music/Ellis - Clear My Head.mp3'),
  }
```

And in your Player2 file, import with the following line:

```
import mediaFiles from '../Utils/mediaFiles';
```

And you should be able to use it like this,

```
this.state = {
          playlist: [
          {id: 1, name:'Catch Me When I Fall', author: 'Arc North ft. Sarah de Warren', img: mediaFiles.img1, audio: mediaFiles.track1}]
```

FYI: update your paths accordingly

Comment: This looks like a clean solution when I tested it. Thanks! 